# Attempt to invoke interface method <MyInterfaceMethord> on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, json

Im new to Android and Im devoloping an application that attempts to connect a server and fetches a Json responce, parse it to a class and let it usable.

Ive implimented 3 classes for this

1. public class Customer{}
2. public class ServerConnect{}
3. public class JsonParser{}

The Serverconnect uses Volley library to download webpage source on an Async thread. After downloaded, Server Connect class fires up a onServerResponded(String responce) listner. This responce is the input to JsonParser class. After JsonParser class fetches customers list succesfully, It fires another listner called onCustomersParsed(List customers). Later processing is done inside onCustomersParsed callback.

But Im getting a FATAL EXCEPTION..

> Attempt to invoke interface method 'void
>   app.utilities.JsonParser$OnCustomersParserListner.onCustomersParsed()'
>   on a null object reference

I've tried my best but I fails. Here are my codes

```
package app.elements;

/**
 * Created by Sangeeth Nandakumar on 13-02-2017.
 */

public class Customer
{
    private String id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String device;
    private String gender;

    public Customer(String id, String firstname, String lastname, String device,String gender)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.device = device;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getDevice() {
        return device;
    }

    public void setDevice(String device) {
        this.device = device;
    }
}
```

THIS IS MY SERVER CONNECTOR CLASS

```
package app.utilities;

import android.content.Context;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

/**
 * Created by Sangeeth Nandakumar on 18-02-2017.
 * Highly optimised Google's Volley driven async webpage source downloader
 */

public class ServerConnector
{
    //Member variables
    private Context context;

    //Override interfaces
    public interface OnServerStatusListner
    {
        public void onServerResponded(String responce);
        public void onServerRevoked();
    }

    //New listner
    private OnServerStatusListner listner;

    //Listner function
    public void setOnServerStatusListner(OnServerStatusListner myststus)
    {
        listner=myststus;
    }

    //Constructor
    public ServerConnector(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    //Connect to server
    public void connectServer(String url)
    {
        //Create a request queue
        RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        //Tunnel the request
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                //When request success
                new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response)
                    {
                        listner.onServerResponded(response);
                    }
                },
                //When request fails
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                    {
                        listner.onServerRevoked();
                    }
                });
        //Add the request to queue
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

}
```

THIS IS MY JSON-PARSER CLASS

```
package app.utilities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import app.elements.Customer;

/**
 * Created by Sangeeth Nandakumar on 18-02-2017.
 * Highly optimised Json parserclass with multiple listners
 */

public class JsonParser
{
    //Data members
    private Context context;
    private String jsontext;
    private List<Customer> customers=new ArrayList<>();

    //Listner object
    public OnCustomersParserListner listner;

    //Listners
    public interface OnCustomersParserListner
    {
        public void onCustomersParsed(List<Customer> customers);
    }

    //On Jsonparse listner
    public void setOnJsonParseListner(OnCustomersParserListner mylistner)
    {
        listner=mylistner;
    }

    //Constructor
    public JsonParser(Context context, String jsontext)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.jsontext = jsontext;
    }

    //Json pre-parsing
    public void parseCustomers()
    {
        // If json is true
        if (jsontext != null)
        {
            try
            {
                //Create a JSON object
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsontext);
                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray json = jsonObj.getJSONArray("details");
                // Looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject details = json.getJSONObject(i);
                    //Get all customer details from JSON file
                    String id = details.getString("id");
                    String firstname = details.getString("firstname");
                    String lastname = details.getString("lastname");
                    String device = details.getString("device");
                    String gender = details.getString("gender");
                    //Add to list
                    customers.add(new Customer(id,firstname,lastname,device,gender));
                }
                listner.onCustomersParsed(customers);
            }
            catch (final JSONException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error in parsing JSON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "JSON text is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

THIS IS THE CALL FROM MAIN ACTIVITY

```
ServerConnector server=new ServerConnector(this);
server.connectServer("http://amazinginside.esy.es/customerlist.php");

server.setOnServerStatusListner(new ServerConnector.OnServerStatusListner()
{
    @Override
    public void onServerResponded(String responce)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Server responded",      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        JsonParser parser=new JsonParser(getApplicationContext(),responce);
        parser.parseCustomers();
        parser.setOnJsonParseListner(new JsonParser.OnCustomersParserListner() {
            @Override
            public void onCustomersParsed(List<Customer> customers) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, customers.get(0).getFirstname(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public void onServerRevoked()
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connection to server broke", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Anyone please help me

Comment: try changing the order of setting listener and calling the parseCustomers in MainActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the listener afterwards calling for `parsing`. Try changing the order.

```
@Override
public void onServerResponded(String responce)
{
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Server responded",      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    JsonParser parser=new JsonParser(getApplicationContext(),responce);
    parser.setOnJsonParseListner(new JsonParser.OnCustomersParserListner() {
        @Override
        public void onCustomersParsed(List<Customer> customers) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, customers.get(0).getFirstname(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    parser.parseCustomers();

}
```

Comment: What a stupid am I.! Thank you my friend. Now everything works fine as you said. Thankyou